# Why does not BeatifulSoup work well with the website Coinmarketcap?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory, real-time-data

I have a problem with the following code. When I run it in Google Colaboratory, I expect the result (a numerical data from the website Coinmarketcap) to be changing over time because it is changing continuously on the website, but I always get a fixed result. How can I fix the problem?

Your help would be highly appreciated:)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
while True:
     url="https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
     html_content = requests.get(url).text

     soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
     h = soup.find(class_='statsValue___2iaoZ').text.replace('$', '').replace('%','')
     print(f'\r{h}', end=" ")
```

> 880,648,583,648 (not changing):(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values update dynamically through javascript. BeautifulSoup can't process that. You can use Selenium instead:

```
!apt update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium
```

Then:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

url="https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get(url)

while True:
     soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, "lxml")
     h = soup.find(class_='statsValue___2iaoZ').text.replace('$', '').replace('%','')
     print(f'\r{h}', end=" ")
```

The values will now update as desired.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when the page first loads, it loads to a set a value and then is updated.
I suggest using this or another site
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/